# Libconfig++ for windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, libconfig

I have a project which was created under linux, it uses libconfig++. I need to port this project to windows, but I couldn’t find a way to install libconfig++ on windows. Is there any way to do it? Thanks in advance.

P.s. i’m not into c++ that much yet, just started learning and already have this task.

Comment: Are you using a MinGW compiler (GCC)? Either stand-alone or as part of MSYS2? Then both have package systems similar to most Linux distributions. You could look to see if the library already exists in the package system. Otherwise, download and build from source, like you would on any Linux system, using the MinGW or MSYS2 shell.

Comment: Also, [the libconfig homepage](https://hyperrealm.github.io/libconfig/) say that there's an included Visual Studio project file included, so it can be built with Visual Studio if that's your environment on Windows.

Comment: Im using qt creator with MinGW 7.3.0, thanks for your response, gonna try to do it